# UICollectionViewController Issue with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have data on my Parse database and I am trying to retrieve that data and show into a UILabel under a UICollectionViewCell.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 PFQuery *retrieveClass = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
    [retrieveClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objets, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
           classArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objets];
            NSLog(@"%@", objets);
        }
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return classArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *tempDict = [classArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.label.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"Name"]);

    return cell;
}
```

classArray is an NSArray and I created a UICollectionViewCell file and created a UILabel then imported into my main file.

I added the cell identifier, made the connections and I don't know what is wrong.

The classnames are right, the field names are right, the parse ID's and ClientKeys are right.

I am getting log feedback under the query block but nothing under the UICollectionViewCell.

Log output
[image]

Comment: Call table view reload method in query block.This will call delegate methods again with filled array.

Comment: @bunty I don't think the issue is from the query block because I am getting stuff back from the NSLog. I'm not getting anything when I set the UILabel under UICollectionViewCell

Comment: @bunty But I did try your suggestion and it only crashed

Comment: Can you show output of NSLog(@"%@", objets) ?

Comment: @bunty Yea I put it up on the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with reload data

```
[retrieveClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objets, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
       classArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objets];
       NSLog(@"%@", objets);
       [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Still you'll get any updated values, then call it with `dispatch_async` block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

Label value will be `cell.label.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Name"];`

Hopefully, it'll help you.

Thanks

Comment: It only crashes. And I don't think it was anything to do with refreshing because it is under the ViewDidLoad and I am getting data through the NSLog but I'm not getting any Log feedback under the UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
cell.label.text = [classArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with

```
cell.label.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Comment: Oh whoops, I was actually experimenting with something and forgot to change it to that. And I did try it and didn't work unfortunately. The classname is right and the field names are right as well

Comment: Now calling reload method should work. Is there any crash yet after calling reload. Try printing count of objects in block to make sure there are at least one object returned from Parse.

Comment: Yes, I made those changes and calling it to reload still didn't work for me. And just to make sure we're on the right page, you call to reload like this [self.collectionView reloadData]; right?